# What is the term for a group of graphs?

Tags: terminology

I know the term for a group of trees is a "forest", but what is the term for a group of graphs?

The difference between a graph and a tree is that a tree can have no cycles, and usually has a node specified as the "root".

Comment: Well... technically, "group of graphs" is naturally a graph, while there is no obvious way to view "group of trees" as a tree. I'd be surprised if there was a distinct name for group of graphs.

Answer (score 1):

What you are thinking of as a "graph" is actually a [*connected graph*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedGraph.html).  In general, a graph need not be connected, i.e. it could have many distinct parts which are all separate, called its "connected components".

The analagous statement to "a colection of trees is a forest" is **"a collection of connected graphs is a graph."**

Answer (score 0):

It's a graph. In fact, a forest is a graph too, not a group of graphs. It's just that a forest isn't a *connected* graph. The individual connected parts of a single graph are called components.  Technically what you're calling a "group of graphs" is a graph, and what you're calling a "graph" is a connected graph.